# Align one child element to the left when parent aligns all child elements to the center

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have a DIV set to align all child elements CENTER with `text-align: center;` but I would like to have one of the child elements aligned to the left, while keeping the rest centered.

How can I achieve this?

I tried to float left that element but it messed up my design since I am not using float at all.

```
.parent {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.child (I want to align this one left) {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Bold', Helvetica neue, verdana, arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #5a8da3;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: set the class of that child div as "child left" and in css specify the style as .child.left{//style}

Comment: A -1 should include a comment explaining why. This question is very licit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go by this. But trying to visualize some of your future problems with this requirement when integrating with future code. The best way to do it is using different positions.

You want all div elements of a parent to be centered apart from one in particular. If you do not give a display property to the one div you want to the left it will **NOT** obey the parent's CSS rule: *text-align:center;*

I used the display property on all div elements that I want to be centered but I set the CSS rule: *position:relative;* to the parent. This will force all child divs with *position:absolute;* to be bound by the parent. Therefore I can set the properties top and left to the child div that I want to put on the left and these properties will be calculated based on the parent width and not the browser's window.

This is the best solution because a child div positioned absolute will not affect the structured template and therefore will not push centered div away from the center of the parent when you add more in future.

Here is your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/77wc17yo/

You can now move your left div using CSS properties: top, left, bottom, right.

```
.parent {
  background:#fefefe;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

.centerd {
   border:1px solid green;
  background:gold;
  padding:90px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.left {
  padding:40px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background:orange;
  width:40px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:20px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/852ewccc/2/

I used a `float: left` on the left-hand div, and a `margin: 0 auto;` to center the other div.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">

    </div>
    <div id="center">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
#center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
#left{
    width: 100px;
    background: orange;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: because they align left naturaly you dont need to add `float:left` to the css for the element you want floated left and by removing `float:left` the centered will sit below the div that is on the left

Comment: @samyb8 - Updated. To be fair you didn't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wafoyyLz/

Float would've been the best option, you should look into making your other elements float, but if you only want text-align to one specific element:

```
HTML:
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children"> Child 1 </div>
    <div class="children"> Child 2 </div>
    <div class="children alignLeft"> Child 3 </div>
    <div class="children"> Child 4 </div>
    <div class="children"> Child 5 </div>
</div>

CSS:
.parent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.alignLeft {
    background-color: #5a8da3;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Doing it this way allows you to add the class to other children either by hardcoding it or using JQuery's add/remove class.

Bear in mind this will not work on all types of elements.

Comment: This only works when .alignLeft divs are 100% of the width, if they are smaller in width the div will align center and the text within it left, which doesnt help since I need the whole .alignLeft div to the left

Comment: Hence why you should float your divs. Plus, don't expect a better answer than this when you don't provide enough details (e.g. show your html or a live page)...