# How to disconnect different hyperlinks in 1 div?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website where I have one hyperlink in an image that should be on the left side of the navigation bar and 4 hyperlink buttons on the other side of the bar but they stay together but I can't find out how to make sure they don't follow the same style to make sure the hyperlink (picture) and the other hyperlink (buttons) are on the other side.

```css
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #253237;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.topnav a img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 55%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="img" href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo-header.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="overmij.php">Over mij</a>
  <a href="Webshop.php">Webshop</a>
  <a href="Contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Maybe for extra clarity I want the image to float left and the other 4 hyperlinks to float right. But I don't know how to get them in other classes so my CSS doesn't think it is the same.

I already tried adding a class to the hyperlink picture and making a div around it

(for the record, I am a beginning hobby programmer)

Comment: We don't debug images here. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Also, revise to clarify what "disconnect them" means. Do you want to add space between them?

Comment: Re edit: "(for the record, i am a beginning hobby programmer)" — That should not prevent you from following the advice isherwood gave you.

Comment: sorry i missed the comment i altered the info after to the best i could

Comment: We need your code. Not an image of your code. Specifically, a [mcve]

Comment: Your question seems to tie to positioning of elements - which to me is about the CSS; please consider adding a functional snippet of your code with that CSS as outlined in the linked reference pages.  There are a lot of ways to do this and what you have will help us best assist you on the direction you have been going.

Comment: Thanks for adding your CSS. However, this is what we call an "nth duplicate" on the site; it has been asked and answered _many times_. Here is one duplicate target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551502/align-one-child-element-to-the-left-when-parent-aligns-all-child-elements-to-the

Comment: the link you sent is about mutiple div`s but i already tried using divs but everything gets out of place when i try that

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers, i found away that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Take example from this code I have changed few things. Check the result by running this code.

```css
.topnav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-image {

    float: left !important;
    height: 40px;
}

.navbar-menu-item {
    place-content: end;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="img" class="logo-image" href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo-header.png" alt="Logo" /></a>

<div class="navbar-menu-item">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="overmij.php">Over mij</a>
  <a href="Webshop.php">Webshop</a>
  <a href="Contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: thankyou for the reaction, i found this earlier but this was indeed the thing that fixed it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).